Constructing a tree starting from some initial vertex
Is it possible to always construct any required tree starting initially with any of the vertices?
I had the following algorithm in mind:

Take the initial vertex, scan all its neighbours, join them.
Go to any of the neighbour, and do the 1st step again
Do the steps until all of the vertices have been covered.

According to me, this should work. But my professor told that it is not always possible to construct any arbitrary tree by using this method.
Please clarify this.

Constructing a tree starting with the vertices of what? Are you trying to construct a spanning tree (or some other kind of tree) in relation to an existing graph? Please clarify this.

We already have a tree given. I was trying to ask whether it is possible to construct the same tree starting from any of the vertices, given that we know neighbours of each vertex.

If we already have a tree given, then joining each vertex to all of its neighbors in the tree will just... give you the same tree back again. This doesn't make sense as a thing you'd want to do, so I think I still don't understand you.

Yes thats what I am saying, so this algorithm, with minor changes as suggested by @Red five, should be able to construct any tree. My professor didn't agree, he was saying something about different structures of subtrees, which I did not understand

If you're starting with a tree, it cannot construct any tree - just the tree you started with. This isn't an interesting thing to say, so if you asked your professor about it, he probably assumed that you were asking about a more interesting problem. For example, if instead you're trying to construct a spanning tree of a larger graph, this algorithm will not be able to construct all of them.

A tree will include all vertices.
Therefore you can start at any vertex.
You do not need to scan all the neighboring vertices, so long as you connect the current vertex with an isolated vertex, you will eventually create a tree, by definition.
If the edges are weighted, this is basically Prim's algorithm, so I don't see how this cannot work.
Edit Perhaps the professor was saying you cannot connect all the neighboring vertices to the current vertex as that may create multiple edges or cycles. So if you change your algorithm slightly to only include isolated vertices, it should work fine.
